# Capturing URLs within the beforeunload event

Tags: events, location, onbeforeunload

When a user navigates away from my page the onBeforeUnload event triggers a confirmation box to be displayed to the user. At this point is there a method by which I can capture the URL that the user is navigating to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditto AnthonyWJones. The language has been limited in this regard intentionally for security/privacy reasons.

Answer (score 2):

No.  That could potentially give info away to an unauthorized party.